# Search in a webpage using bash

Tags: bash, full-text-search, substring

I am trying to retrieve a webpage, search it for some pattern, retrieve that value and do some calculations with it. My Problem is, i can't seem to figure out how to search for the pattern in a given string.

Lets say i retrieve a Page like this

```
content=$(curl -L http://google.com)
```

now i want to search for a value im interested in, which is basically a html tag.

```
<div class="digits">123,456,789</div>
```

No i did try to find this by using sed. My Attempt looked like this:

```
n=$(echo "$content"|sed '<div class=\"digits\">(\\d\\d,\\d\\d\\d,\\d\\d\\d)</div>')
```

i want to pull that value every, lets say 10 minutes, save it and estimate when 124,xxx,xxx will be met.

My Problem is i don't really know how to save those values, but i think i can figure that out on my own. Im more interested in how to retrieve that substring as i always get an error because of the "<".

i hope someone is able and willing to help me :)

Comment: Did you mean `grep` instead of `sed`?

Comment: usually i dont use bash for stuff like this, but i am willing to learn it. The examples i found used sed, but it doesnt seem to work for me :(
Would you be willing to fix this? =D
or can i just replace sed with grep?

Answer (score 1):

Better use a proper parser with [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//*[@class="digits"]' http://domain.tld/
```

But it seems that the example url you gave in the comments don't contains this class name. You can prove it by running first :

```
curl -Ls url | grep -oP '<div\s+class="digits">\K[^<]+'
```

Comment: leaves me with failed to load external entity, i know that the adress provided works. Any suggestions?

Comment: hm, then it wont return anything. Basically what im trying to do is to retrieve that class from robertspaceindustries.com to estimate when next fundinggoal is reached :P
And i know for a fact that the div has the pattern as written above

Comment: There's no `class="digits"` from within `curl -Ls robertspaceindustries.com` nor from within `firefox` :/ Sure that will never match !

Comment: there is, but i figured the value comes from javascript, so i would have to wait for the page to run the javascripts, and then pull it.
Verified that it is there, when loading page with google chrome. <div class="digits">310,645</div> this is what i want to retrieve from the page

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use a proper parser as @sputnick suggested.

Or you can try something like this:

```
curl -L url | perl -ne '/<div class="digits">([\d,]+)<.div>/ && {print $1, "\n"}'
```